# Overlay not working when uploaded onto live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

Still struggling with this thing. I have an overlay that works in IE on my local machine, but when I upload it to my server (and run it in Chrome), the overlay appears briefly and then closes again.

I presume that I've dine the genius thing of include duplicate references and have played around with removing some. I've managed to get the Overlay appearing again, but it appears "disabled" / greyed out and can't take any input.

Can someone please help?

two links are: [Site 1](http://www.biteconsulting.co.za/3001.html)
[Site2](http://www.biteconsulting.co.za/bt3001.html)

Comment: Please add your code, it will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybaroe2a/11/

Comment: first check you jquery.min.js file i think you have error on line no 204 solve it and try

Comment: in second web page first load jquery and then load bootstrap.js because bootstrap use jquery. see your console so you can understand where you was wrong

Comment: check your inspect element there are some error

Comment: @QSTrain did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you're loading in `bootstrap.min.js` twice.

The other issue is in your CSS. On your JSfiddle, you have CSS that you didn't include on your site (can verify by viewing source code).

So delete the duplicate references, and add in the missing CSS from JSfiddle.

```
.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}
```